# Javascript promise( Async/Await ) implement on Node api

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    var x, y, z;
    setTimeout(() => {
        x = 10
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        y = 20
    }, 3000);


    setTimeout(() => {
        z = x+y
    }, 2000);

    res.send('The sum is'+ z);
})
```

now the API response is undefined, but if I write the `setTimeout()` one into another

```
   setTimeout(()=> {
      setTimeout(()=>{
          ....
      });
   });
```

Then it works fine. How can I solve that with Promise and Async/Await

Comment: because your last setTimeout will trigger first and it tries to add x and y which does not have the value at that time, Also the res.send will invoke immediately without waiting for the setTimeouts and will return undefined for the variable z.

Comment: You canuse Promise.all() to resolve all Promises at once.

Comment: last setTimeOut is small so it will execute before x and y. so if you want delay then give x and y delay less then z delay so that x and y get initialized

Comment: Yes I got it @Tick20 && Amit Tiwary

Comment: @GeorgeBailey can you please solve this using async/await this answer is too much described and solved on ajax request but I need to implement that with Node api..

Comment: someone solve the problem with async and await please

Comment: One more note: Using `setTimeout` doesn't ensure that your code will run in the order you want, even if the timeout's order is OK: `setTimeout` ensures your code won't run bedore the given time, but it may execute later, so to make a failsafe approach, you have to check that the previous timeout has finished. Here is where Promises are handy...